# C# - fast way to compare 2 integers, bit by bit, and output for more than one integer, possible?

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have two input integer numbers and an output list< int> myoutputlist.  My inputs are lets say
A=0x**110101**
B=0x**101100**

then I have calculated a C integer number depending on A and B numbers.I already coded its algorithm, I can calculate C integer. C integer shows which bits should be changed. 1 value represents changing bits, 0 values represents unchanging bits. Only one bit should be changed in each time. As C integer depends on A and B inputs,  sometimes 1 bit, sometimes 3 bits, sometimes 8 bits needs to be changed. In this given A and B values, I have C integer as follows

C=0x 0**1**00**1**0   (1 represents changing values; second and fifth bits should be changed in this case)

As C integer has value "1" for two times; there should be 2 results in this case

result 1-Changing only second bit, other bits are same as A(0x110101) :
Change second bit of A =>  D1=1101 **1** 1

result 2-Changing only fifth bit, other bits are same as A(0x110101) :
Change fifth bit of A =>   D2=1 **1** 0101

What I am thinking  is using a for loop, shifting A and C step by step, and using &1 mask to C? And check if it is equal to "1"

```
for(i=0;i<32;i++)  
{int D=(C>>i)&1;     //I tried to check if i.th value is equal to 1 or not
 if(D==1) 
   {   int E=(A&(~(2^i))) | ((2^i)&(~B)) //in first brackets, I removed i.th bit of A, then replaced it with "not B" value.  
       myoutputlist.add(E); 
   }
}
```

I need to do lots of calculations but disturbing issue is that I need to check (D==1) for 32 times. I will use it many million times, some calculations take about 2 mins. I am looking for a faster way. Is there any idea, trick?

Comment: Do a benchmark and compare your different ideas to see whether they are slow or not for your current scenario.

Comment: @stakx, thank you stakx, yes you are right, so my codes are working billion billion times, it takes more than 2 minutes..

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Try to clearly define what the inputs are, and what the outputs are. You are also asking which "way" is faster, but it's also not apparent what the different "ways" you are considerering are.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understood your question right.

You are looking for the **XOR** operator.

```
C = A ^ B

A 110101
B 101100
--------
C 011001
```

**XOR** will always be 1 if the two inputs are "different". See:

```
| A | B | XOR |
|---+---+-----|
| 0 | 0 |  0  |
| 0 | 1 |  1  |
| 1 | 0 |  1  |
| 1 | 1 |  0  |
```

Then you will be able to loop through the bits of `C` like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
{
    bool bit = (C & (1 << i)) != 0;
}
```

Comment: thank you bytecode77, In your explanation,according to value of C, I need to change first, fourth and fifth values of A one by one, finally, I will have 3 versions of A, possible?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "3 versions of A." C in this case is a mask that determinates which bits should be changed and with the for-loop you can do whatever you like to those bits.

Comment: I don't think there's a direct way using bit-manipulation to do this. You have to use the loop (as in my example) and loop your way through it.

Comment: You can also loop through only the set bits (instead of testing them all) using `x & (x - 1)` (or one of its relatives), may not help much though.